# Is my claim valid for the maximum and minimum of the function $(\cos x)+ A\, (\cos y)$?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, trigonometry, inequality

I have this function $f$ for real $A$ and $0<x,y<2\pi$.

$$ (\cos x)+ A\, (\cos y)= f$$

From the identities $ \mid\cos x \mid\leq 1 $ and $ \mid\cos y \mid\leq 1 $, we have
$$  -1\leq\cos x \leq 1 \qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad (1)$$
$$  -A\leq A\cos y \leq A \qquad if \qquad A>0\qquad\qquad\qquad (2)$$
$$  A\leq A\cos y \leq -A \qquad if \qquad A<0\qquad\qquad\qquad (3)$$

Then, using the inequality summation rules, can I claim that

$$ (1),(2)\qquad\qquad -A-1\leq f \leq A+1 \qquad if \qquad A>0$$
$$ (1),(3)\qquad\qquad A-1\leq f \leq 1-A \qquad if \qquad A<0$$

Comment: In fact yes, it is a particular case of the answer I have given to your previous [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4300364) asked an hour ago.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to find a constraint over the parameters $f,g,h$ in the equation $ f \,(\cos x)+ g\, (\cos y)= h\,$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4300364/is-it-possible-to-find-a-constraint-over-the-parameters-f-g-h-in-the-equation)

Comment: @Zaragosa They are a bit different :)

Answer (score 1):

Your claim is valid by the properties of $\mathbb{R}$ and its ordering '$\leq$'. If $$\alpha \leq x \leq \beta$$ and $$\gamma \leq y \leq \nu,$$ then
$$\alpha + \gamma \leq x+y \leq \beta + \nu.$$
So what you have shown is just a direct application of the inequality summation rules. Also, note that you can write your results in terms of a single inequality. Indeed, by use of the triangle inequality we have $|f| \leq 1 + |A|$, hence
$$-|A| -1 \leq f \leq 1 + |A|,$$
which is identical to your two cases when $A >0$ or $A<0$.